# Highly conditional Rails 3 views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I've got a Rails 3 application where I'm using quite a few conditional statements to change the design of the page. What is the best practice for keeping the logic out of the view for having such drastic amounts of conditionals?

Hypothetical Example:

```
<% unless @ethos.blank? %>
 <%= unless @work.nil? do %>
  <%= link_to "Add Work", work_path %>
 <% end %>   
 <%= @ethos.tagline %>
<% end %>
```

I've got many more conditionals inside of other conditionals. What is the best way to manage this inside of one view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid complex conditionals (and most conditionals) in views. Extract them to a Helper, or better yet, to some kind of "presenter" so that you can work with a receiver instead of those "global looking/feeling helpers"

SomeHelper

```
module SomeHelper
  def work_link
    (@ethos.present? && @work) ? link_to("Add Work", work_path) : nil
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= work_link %>
<%= @ethos.tagline if @ethos.present? %>
```

If `@ethos` is likely to be `nil` as opposed to an empty `[]` array, you could instead use:

```
<%= @ethos.try :tagline  %>
```

Also note that in your original view `<%= unless @work.nil? do %>` should have been using a `-` and not a `=`.

Oh, and I encourage you to use [HAML](http://haml.info/) over ERB. With HAML, the view looks like this (easier to read, isn't it) :

```
= work_link %>
= @ethos. try :tagline
```

Your original view would look like this in HAML (remember, avoid conditionals in views as much as possible!)

```
- unless @ethos.blank?
 - unless @work.nil? do
   = link_to "Add Work", work_path
 = @ethos.tagline
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code works, what is your concern? Is it aesthetics or are you having difficulty reasoning about what the code is doing because there is so much nesting?.

The simplest solution is probably just to move the conditionals inline.

```
<%= link_to("Add Work", work_path) if @ethos.present? && @work %>
<%= @ethos.tagline if @ethos.present? %>
```

This will improve readability (and therefore maintainability), though it may not go far enough to keep the Rails purists happy. Zabba's answer presents several great choices that go further down the rabbit hole.